# How to create a 'private' wireless network using the a laptop with an ethernet connection?

Tags: networking, hotspot

I am doing a project that requires using Kali Linux an Ettercap to perform a man in the middle attack.

I need to scan the wireless network for hosts.The problem is that I only have access to the colleges network - a scan returns hundreds of connected hosts and I am not allowed to use these.

I am wondering if it is possible to create 'private' wireless network using using an Ethernet connection to the colleges network for internet, so that I can use my laptop as a wireless hot spot and only scan connected devices?

Comment: It is not possible to create a wireless network using an Ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take the question as you have a Ethernet cable to the computer for Internet connection and you want to share it through your Wi-Fi.

This is an answer I found on Kali Linux forums by the user MasterButcher, so in other words, *I make no claim for the validity of this information, nor have I had the chance to test this.*

And because the super user, Kali Linux, and Man in the Middle attacks are being used I am going to include the all important...

***Disclamer:** I, the poster of this answer, am not responsible for any data loss or loss of any other kind by those (the readers) that use this guide/answer. The reader/user continues at the risk of their own data and system integrity. Furthermore, I, the poster of this answer, will not, and cannot, be held liable for any other data compromised, exploited, stolen, etc. through the use of this method on Kali Linux, or any other operating system. In other words, I am not liable for any trouble, legal or otherwise, the user/reader may get themselves into.*

I would also check with your campus if opening a Wi-Fi hot-spot like this using the campus' Internet is acceptable.

With that out of the way on to my answer:

From the [Kali Linux forums](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?4643-Create-Hotsopt-on-Kali-linux) (with some reformatting so it doesn't appear as a glob of a quote) :

> Hotspot share your computer's Internet connection with other devices over Wi-Fi.
>
> Find wireless driver and make sure that driver is ath5k or ath9k, this solution will only work for those drivers. 
>
>     For others wireless cards and drivers for now doesn't work...
>
>     1. In terminal type: `lspci`
>     If you use usb wireless adapter type command lsusb.
>
>     We now need to install 2 additional tools to make out hotspot, 1st one is hostapd(hotspot server), 2nd one is dnsmasq(dns dhcp server).
>
>     2. `apt-get install hostapd dnsmasq`
>
>     3. Stop those services if started already, and prevent them from starting on system start up.
>
>     in terminal type:
>     
>     `sudo service hostapd stop
>     sudo service dnsmasq stop
>     sudo update-rc.d hostapd disable
>     sudo update-rc.d dnsmasq disable`
>     
>
>     4. Now we need to set up config files.
>     in terminal type: 
> `gedit /etc/dnsmasq.conf`
>     or `kate /etc/dnsmasq.conf` if you use kde...
>
>     add those lines to the config file:
>     
>     `# Bind to only one interface
>     bind-interfaces
>     # Choose interface for binding
>     interface=wlan0
>     # Specify range of IP addresses for DHCP leasses
>     dhcp-range=192.168.150.2,192.168.150.10`
>     
>
>     5. hostapd config
>     In terminal type: `gedit /etc/hostapd.conf` and add those lines:
>     
>     `# Define interface
>     interface=wlan0
>     # Select driver
>     driver=nl80211
>     # Set access point name
>     ssid=myhotspot
>     # Set access point hardware mode to 802.11g
>     hw_mode=g
>     # Set WIFI channel (can be easily changed)
>     channel=6
>     # Enable WPA2 only (1 for WPA, 2 for WPA2, 3 for WPA + WPA2)
>     wpa=2
>     wpa_passphrase=mypassword`
>     
>     You can change ssid name and password for anything you want here. Current config will create hotspot named myhotspot with password mypassword.
>
>     6. Now create anywhere you want a file named it hotspot.sh (best way to save script on Desktop)
>     Edit it with any text editor like this:
>     
>     `#!/bin/bash
>     # Start
>     # Configure IP address for WLAN
>     sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.150.1
>     # Start DHCP/DNS server
>     sudo service dnsmasq restart
>     # Enable routing
>     sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
>     # Enable NAT
>     sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
>     # Run access point daemon
>     sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf
>     # Stop
>     # Disable NAT
>     sudo iptables -D POSTROUTING -t nat -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
>     # Disable routing
>     sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
>     # Disable DHCP/DNS server
>     sudo service dnsmasq stop
>     sudo service hostapd stop`
>     
>
>     You will probably need to change ppp0 in this to eth0 or any other number which refers to your wired connection.
>
>     7. Last step. Now you can start your hotspot by starting script. Just run it...
>     For me it looks like this:
>     
>     `root@kali:~# cd /root/Desktop/
>     root@kali:~/Desktop# ./hotspot.sh`
>     
>     Because I have it on my Desktop.
>
>     Enjoy in your new Hotspot!!!!!!
>
>
>     By MasterButcher

The only other thing I can think to add is don't forget to use

`chmod +x hotspot.sh`

To enable the execution bit for the script.

Hope this Helps!